# OpenTelemetry transaction has http.route set to "api/{controller}/{action}"

Tags: asp.net, open-telemetry

I have legacy .NET 4.6.2 application that had to be monitored with OpenTelemetry. After going back and forth with implementation, I managed to send traces to Kibana, however the most of the them contain endpoint addresses like this - **api/{controller}/{action}**, and not the actual endpoint.
I am investigating this and only in couple of occasions here and there is a word about OpenTelemetry is not handling properly endpoints that have route set in a attribute, like:

```
        [Route("api/products/{productCode}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetProductData(string code)
        {
            \\some code
        }
```

There is no details how to be fixed, or I am not able to find them.

Is there anything that could be done in this case? Legacy system that I am working on contains around 20 controllers and more than 80 endpoints, so managing routes would be very challenging.

Edit: I have forgot to mention that this behavior doesn't happened in console exporter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC and found a custom solution. After creating the TraceProvider:

```
_tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
       .AddSource("my-service-name")
       .SetResourceBuilder(
           ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
              .AddService(serviceName: "my-service-name", serviceVersion: "1.0.0"))
       .AddAspNetInstrumentation()
       .AddJaegerExporter()
       .Build();
```

I did the following:

```
var opts = OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNet.TelemetryHttpModule.Options;
var actualRequestStoppedCallback = opts.OnRequestStoppedCallback;

opts.OnRequestStoppedCallback = (System.Diagnostics.Activity activity, HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    actualRequestStoppedCallback?.Invoke(activity, httpContext);

    var request = httpContext.Request;
    var requestContext = request.RequestContext;
    var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;
    string template = null;
    if (routeData.Route is Route route)
    {
        // This is the part that generates the path
        var vpd = route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeData.Values);
        template = "/" + vpd.VirtualPath;
    }
    
    if (template != null)
    {
        // And here i set the new generated path
        activity.DisplayName = template;
        activity.SetTag("http.route", template);
    }
};
```

You can adapt this to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks!
I need to go trough your code in detail as soon as I find the time. For now, my legacy app is going through decommission,  so I cannot change any implementation, but at first glance it looks interesting and promising.